# Is there a way to configure some central push repository to reject history changing pushes?

Tags: git

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You want to set these two configuration variables to true on the central repository.

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards
receive.denyDeletes
```